# MacPorts. Failed to configure cairo

Tags: macports, macos-mojave

I am unable to install the port py37-pymysql (MacOS Mojave 10.14.6):

```
$ sudo port install py37-pymysql
--->  Computing dependencies for py37-pymysql
--->  Cleaning py37-pymysql
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 4 broken files, matching files to ports
--->  Found 4 broken ports, determining rebuild order
You can always run 'port rev-upgrade' again to fix errors.
The following ports will be rebuilt:
 py27-cairo @1.18.1+quartz+x11
 py35-cairo @1.18.1
 harfbuzz @2.5.3
 rb-rcairo @1.14.3
Continue? [Y/n]: y
--->  Computing dependencies for cairo
--->  Configuring cairo
Error: Failed to configure cairo, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/work/cairo-1.16.0/config.log
Error: Failed to configure cairo: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/main.log for details.
Error: Problem while installing cairo
Error: rev-upgrade failed: Error rebuilding py27-cairo
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
```

When I try to run 'port rev-upgrade', I come across the same error:

```
$ sudo port rev-upgrade
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 4 broken files, matching files to ports
--->  Found 4 broken ports, determining rebuild order
You can always run 'port rev-upgrade' again to fix errors.
The following ports will be rebuilt:
 py27-cairo @1.18.1+quartz+x11
 py35-cairo @1.18.1
 harfbuzz @2.5.3
 rb-rcairo @1.14.3
Continue? [Y/n]: y
--->  Computing dependencies for cairo
--->  Configuring cairo
Error: Failed to configure cairo, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/work/cairo-1.16.0/config.log
Error: Failed to configure cairo: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/main.log for details.
Error: Problem while installing cairo
Error: rev-upgrade failed: Error rebuilding py27-cairo
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
```

Something similar happens when i try to install the port cairo by itself:

```
$ sudo port install cairo
--->  Computing dependencies for cairo
--->  Configuring cairo
Error: Failed to configure cairo, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/work/cairo-1.16.0/config.log
Error: Failed to configure cairo: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_cairo/cairo/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port cairo failed
```

I keep running into this error (Failed to configure cairo), when I try to install other ports. I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest a fix to this. Many thanks in advance!